# openldap decrypt cert8.db, keys3.db with password

Tags: openldap

I have to analyze an OpenLDAP configuration where certificates and keys are stored into cert8.db and keys3.db files.

I have associated password file which seems to be used to crypt/decrypt data. There is also a secmod.db file containing among other things:

```
Root Certs /usr/lib64/libnssckbi.so
Root Certs KdNSS Internal PKCS #11 Module
configdir='/etc/openldap/certs'
certPrefix=''
keyPrefix=''
secmod='secmod.db'
flags= updatedir=''
updateCertPrefix=''
updateKeyPrefix=''
updateid=''
updateTokenDescription='' ?=NSS Internal PKCS #11 Module
```

`file` command on `/etc/openldap/certs` returns:

```
cert8.db:  Berkeley DB 1.85 (Hash, version 2, native byte-order)
key3.db:   Berkeley DB 1.85 (Hash, version 2, native byte-order)
password:  ASCII text
secmod.db: Berkeley DB 1.85 (Hash, version 2, native byte-order)
```

However, I can't find a way to decrypt what is stored into these two files. I have tried with pk12util but listing contained certificates returns:

```
pk12util -l cert8.db
Enter password for PKCS12 file:
pk12util: PKCS12 decoding failed: SEC_ERROR_BAD_DER: security library: improperly formatted DER-encoded message.
```

How can I retrieve data from these files ?

EDIT

I also came to read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37644/677163) which advises to use `db_dump`:

```
db_dump -l cert8.db 
db_dump: BDB0210 cert8.db: metadata page checksum error
db_dump: BDB5115 open: cert8.db: Invalid argument
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `certutil` from `nss-tools` (on RHEL/CentOS):

```
certutil -L -d /etc/openldap/certs
```

will give you a list of certs.

```
Certificate Nickname                                         Trust Attributes
                                                             SSL,S/MIME,JAR/XPI

OpenLDAP Server                                              CTu,u,u
```

Export the keys with

```
 pk12util  -o outfile.p12 -d /etc/openldap/certs -n "OpenLDAP Server"
```

This will ask for a password for the the export (it's in the `password` file) and one for the exported key.